# Redis precision Floating point precision problem for monetary values

Tags: redis, lua, ieee-754

I already search for a proper solution to this problem.
The problem is floating point(IEEE 754).
This problem is not new for me... In java I use `BigDecimal`, in JS I use `bignumber.js`.

Unfortunately I could not find a proper solution in Redis. It seems like basic thing that need to be supported so I am sure I am missing something

Example:

```
>set key 100000

>incrbyfloat key -0.0002
```

**Expected: 99,999.9998
Actual: 99999.999800000005**

I thought maybe to implement my own `incrbyfloatbig` in lua and than to use it accross the Redis calculations but I do not know how...

Comment: When you're talking about monetary values - what's the precision you need?
Usually in money transactions like in a web shop only 2 digits are used, for bank accounts this might be a different thing.
Some ideas that came to my mind: Just round it or maybe even better, use integer values and divide them by 10^x in your code.

Comment: I am using it for crypto. There are a lot of digits after the decimal point.. For Example: Ethereum smallest value is 0.000000000000000001

Comment: This is actually a base and representation problem, not a precision problem. The floating-point format being used is binary based—it represents numbers as multiples of powers of two, including negative powers such as ½, ¼, ⅛, and so on. .0002 is not an exact multiple of any power of two, so it can never be represented exactly in a binary format, no matter how much precision you have. To do exact arithmetic with a binary base, you will have to choose a unit of measurement that is representable, such as using attoEthereum (10**-18 Ethereum) instead of Ethereum as the unit.

Comment: Once you have chosen a unit, then you may need to exercise some care about the operations and values you use. If you need to manipulate whole Ethereum using units of 10**18, the numbers may exceed what is representable in the floating-point format. That is a precision problem, since the limit is the number of bits being used, rather than the base, and the floating-point format may be inadequate for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will be glad to get a link to a source or something.. because i was sure the problem is floating point and i couldn't find anything.

Comment: Regarding to the solution.. it may be a problem because i guess there is a lot crypto currencies with very small unit. And if i will make this change which is very wide change i need to know the limitations i have.. do you have some kind of examples for the solution? Big nunber library or something similiar that will give me a solution to go into the smallest unit journey?